# Failing to use interpolation instead of integration in chuncks with ODE45

Tags: matlab, interpolation, ode, ode45

I have written this code to integrate voltage V and gating conductances m, n and h in 30ms with injection of current from ms 10 to 20. So basically Current I is a vector that has 0 values until 10ms, 1 values until 20ms and 0 values until 30ms. The code works well and it shows the behaviour I want to see.

I'm trying to implement the same code with interpolation instead of integration in chunks. However, I'm failing to do so.

This is the integration with interpolation, which is giving the incorrect result:

```
myode = @(T,y0) [((1/Cm)*interp1(t, I, T, 'linear','extrap')-(INa+IK+Il)); % Normal case
    alpham(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(2,1))-betam(y0(1,1))*y0(2,1);
    alphan(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(3,1))-betan(y0(1,1))*y0(3,1);
    alphah(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(4,1))-betah(y0(1,1))*y0(4,1)];

[time,V] = ode45(myode, t, y0, I);
```

This is the correct one, in chunks:

```
[time,V] = ode45(@ODEMAT, [t(chunk), t(chunk+1)], y);   

%%% Calls ODEMAT, in which theres' the integration (extensive code posted below):

dydt = [((1/Cm)*(I(chunk)-(INa+IK+Il))); % Normal case
    alpham(V)*(1-m)-betam(V)*m;
    alphan(V)*(1-n)-betan(V)*n;
    alphah(V)*(1-h)-betah(V)*h];
```

This is the code with the integration in chunks:

```
function Z2_chunks ()
    %% Initial values
    V=-60; % Initial Membrane voltage
    m1=alpham(V)/(alpham(V)+betam(V)); % Initial m-value
    n1=alphan(V)/(alphan(V)+betan(V)); % Initial n-value
    h1=alphah(V)/(alphah(V)+betah(V)); % Initial h-value
    y0=[V;m1;n1;h1];
    
    t = [1:30];
    I = [zeros(1,10),ones(1,10),zeros(1,10)];
    
    % Plotting purposes (set I(idx) equal to last value of I)
    idx = numel(t);
    I(idx) = 0.1;
    
    chunks = numel(t) - 1;
    
    for chunk = 1:chunks
        
        if chunk == 1
            V=-60; % Initial Membrane voltage
            m=alpham(V)/(alpham(V)+betam(V)); % Initial m-value
            n=alphan(V)/(alphan(V)+betan(V)); % Initial n-value
            h=alphah(V)/(alphah(V)+betah(V)); % Initial h-value
            y=[V;m;n;h];
        else
            y = V(end, :);  % Final position is initial value for next interval
        end
        [time,V] = ode45(@ODEMAT, [t(chunk), t(chunk+1)], y);
        
        if chunk == 1
            def_time = time;
            def_v = V;
        else
            def_time = [def_time; time];
            def_v = [def_v; V];
        end       
    end
    
    OD = def_v(:,1);
    ODm = def_v(:,2);
    ODn = def_v(:,3);
    ODh = def_v(:,4);
    time = def_time;
    
    %% Plots
    %% Voltage
    figure
    subplot(3,1,1)
    plot(time,OD);
    legend('ODE45 solver');
    xlabel('Time (ms)');
    ylabel('Voltage (mV)');
    title('Voltage Change for Hodgkin-Huxley Model');
    
    %% Current
    subplot(3,1,2)
    stairs(t,I)
    ylim([0 5*max(I)])
    legend('Current injected')
    xlabel('Time (ms)')
    ylabel('Ampere')
    title('Current')
    
    %% Gating variables
    subplot(3,1,3)
    plot(time,[ODm,ODn,ODh]);
    legend('ODm','ODn','ODh');
    xlabel('Time (ms)')
    ylabel('Value')
    title('Gating variables')
        
    function [dydt] = ODEMAT(t,y)
        
        %% Constants
        ENa=55; % mv Na reversal potential
        EK=-72; % mv K reversal potential
        El=-49; % mv Leakage reversal potential
        
        %% Values of conductances
        gbarl=0.003; % mS/cm^2 Leakage conductance
        gbarNa=1.2; % mS/cm^2 Na conductance
        gbarK=0.36; % mS/cm^2 K conductancence
        Cm = 0.01; % Capacitance
        
        % Values set to equal input values
        V = y(1);
        m = y(2);
        n = y(3);
        h = y(4);
        
        gNa = gbarNa*m^3*h;
        gK = gbarK*n^4;
        gL = gbarl;
        
        INa=gNa*(V-ENa);
        IK=gK*(V-EK);
        Il=gL*(V-El);
    
        
        dydt = [((1/Cm)*(I(chunk)-(INa+IK+Il))); % Normal case
            alpham(V)*(1-m)-betam(V)*m;
            alphan(V)*(1-n)-betan(V)*n;
            alphah(V)*(1-h)-betah(V)*h]; 
    end
end
```

This is the code with the integration with interpolation. As you can see, the plots are really different:

```
function Z1_interpol () 
    %% Initial values
    V=-60; % Initial Membrane voltage
    m1=alpham(V)/(alpham(V)+betam(V)); % Initial m-value
    n1=alphan(V)/(alphan(V)+betan(V)); % Initial n-value
    h1=alphah(V)/(alphah(V)+betah(V)); % Initial h-value
    y0=[V;m1;n1;h1];
    
    t = [1:30];
    I = [zeros(1,10),ones(1,10),zeros(1,10)];
    
    % Plotting purposes (set I(idx) equal to last value of I)
    idx = numel(t);
    I(idx) = 0.1;   
    
    V=-60; % Initial Membrane voltage
    m=alpham(V)/(alpham(V)+betam(V)); % Initial m-value
    n=alphan(V)/(alphan(V)+betan(V)); % Initial n-value
    h=alphah(V)/(alphah(V)+betah(V)); % Initial h-value
    y=[V;m;n;h];
    
    %% Constants
    ENa=55; % mv Na reversal potential
    EK=-72; % mv K reversal potential
    El=-49; % mv Leakage reversal potential
    
    %% Values of conductances
    gbarl=0.003; % mS/cm^2 Leakage conductance
    gbarNa=1.2; % mS/cm^2 Na conductance
    gbarK=0.36; % mS/cm^2 K conductancence
    Cm = 0.01; % Capacitance
    
    %% Initial values
    V=-60; % Initial Membrane voltage
    m=alpham(V)/(alpham(V)+betam(V)); % Initial m-value
    n=alphan(V)/(alphan(V)+betan(V)); % Initial n-value
    h=alphah(V)/(alphah(V)+betah(V)); % Initial h-value
    y0=[V;m;n;h];
    
    gNa = gbarNa*m^3*h;
    gK = gbarK*n^4;
    gL = gbarl;
    
    INa=gNa*(V-ENa);
    IK=gK*(V-EK);
    Il=gL*(V-El);
    
    myode = @(T,y0) [((1/Cm)*interp1(t, I, T, 'linear','extrap')-(INa+IK+Il)); % Normal case
        alpham(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(2,1))-betam(y0(1,1))*y0(2,1);
        alphan(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(3,1))-betan(y0(1,1))*y0(3,1);
        alphah(y0(1,1))*(1-y0(4,1))-betah(y0(1,1))*y0(4,1)];
    
    [time,V] = ode45(myode, t, y0, I);
    
    OD=V(:,1);
    ODm=V(:,2);
    ODn=V(:,3);
    ODh=V(:,4);
    time = time;
    
    
        %% Plots
    %% Voltage
    figure
    subplot(3,1,1)
    plot(time,OD);
    legend('ODE45 solver');
    xlabel('Time (ms)');
    ylabel('Voltage (mV)');
    title('Voltage Change for Hodgkin-Huxley Model');
    
    %% Current
    subplot(3,1,2)
    stairs(t,I)
    ylim([0 5*max(I)])
    legend('Current injected')
    xlabel('Time (ms)')
    ylabel('Ampere')
    title('Current')
    
    
    %% Gating variables
    subplot(3,1,3)
    plot(time,[ODm,ODn,ODh]);
    legend('ODm','ODn','ODh');
    xlabel('Time (ms)')
    ylabel('Value')
    title('Gating variables')       
    
end
```

Comment: What is the extra argument `I` in the first `ode45` call, and why did you not try to set the error tolerances to some problem-appropriate values?

Comment: Of course the last plot will be different, as the `V` used in the computation of the `I...` variables is a constant, while in the previous 2 codes the `V` used is the first state component and thus variable. /// From the first to the second there will also be a difference as piecewise constant is different from piecewise linear. The `interp1d` function should have a "zero-order hold" mode. /// You might want to explore the `odextend` compagnion function to the ODE integrators. /// Pass the `I(chunk)` value as parameter, easiest with `@(t,y)ODEMAT(t,y,I(chunk))` as function argument.